# Nodejs , Mongoose need to optimize query for faster result while query is under loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## Current execution doesn't have any problem but it take alot of time to return result.

### House Schema

```
const HouseSchema = Schema({
   wardNumber: Number
})
```

### Family Schema

```
const FamilydetailSchema = Schema({
   house: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "house"
   },
   gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true
   },
})
```

### Query to be optimize

```
member = async (ward, gender) => {
    const family = await families.find(gender, "house").populate({
        path: "house",
        match: ward,
        select: "_id"
    });
    if (family) {
        let count = family.filter(({ house }) => house != null).length || 0;
        return count;
    }
};
```

### Calling the above function in loop

```
totalWard = 14;
result = [];

    let voidData = [...Array(totalWard).keys()].map(async each => {
        const ward = each + 1;
        let body = { ward };
        body.ward = each + 1;
        body.male = await member(ward, { gender: "male" });
        body.female = await member(ward, { gender: "female" });
        body.third = await member(ward, { gender: "third_gender" });
        body.total = await member(ward, {});
        
        result.push(body);
    });
    await Promise.all(voidData);
```

Comment: You will need to also show us the Mongoose schema...

Comment: schema is added.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to also wrap

```js
        body.male = await member(ward, { gender: "male" });
        body.female = await member(ward, { gender: "female" });
        body.third = await member(ward, { gender: "third_gender" });
        body.total = await member(ward, {});
```

into a `promise.all` function

Comment: ... And hope the MongoDB server doesn't mind suddenly getting (4 * 14) = 56 parallel queries. I don't think that's the way to optimize this...